# How to access a single row by index in multiindex dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this, where `native-country` and `salary` are indices. And I'd like to know, is it possible to access a a single row by `native-country`, for instance by `Canada`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`DataFrame.xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) (cross-section)

```
df.xs(key='Canada', level=0, drop_level=False)
```